# How can I initiate another test run on QAWolf for a particular test?

Tags: testing

By default, the QAWolf test runs 3 attempts on every test. But there are cases when the tests are flaky and they fail for no reason. Running it again can make the test pass successfully. Is there a way to run a particular test again?

I usually add an empty commit to re-trigger the whole test suite. But that isn't a good solution because then other flaky tests start failing.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option in QAWolf to initiate another run for a particular test.
Open the test and its details. On the top right, there's an option to 'Reattempt with latest version'

[See in this screenshot][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfOUE.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).